# How to design a relational database that has data points (a value and a timestamp) for different unique IDs?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

The database is supposed to contain the information about different virtual machines instances. Each VM has a unique ID, a user, and a "is running" tag. Also, for each ID, there is a list of datapoints for the CPU utilization over the last hour.

I was thinking of creating two tables:

1. Instances(ID, user, isRunning)
2. Datapoints(ID, value, timestamp)

The table 2 would look like that:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+
| ID  | Value | Timestamp |
+-----+-------+-----------+
| ID1 |     . |         . |
| ID1 |     . |         . |
| ID1 |     . |         . |
| ID2 |     . |         . |
| ID2 |     . |         . |
| ID2 |     . |         . |
+-----+-------+-----------+
```

The unique IDs would have to be repeated in the table for the number of datapoints associated with it. I was  wondering if that design would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design will work with following `datapoints` table modifications:

- define primary key as (ID, timestamp)
- add foreign key constraint (datapoints.ID -> instances.ID)

Another options:

- add datapoint item number like `item_num` so primary key will be (ID, item_num)
- add `datapoint_id` column as primary key and make (ID, timestamp) unique

Comment: Why is the primary key (ID, timestamp) without "value" included?

Comment: Because of functional dependency `id, timestamp --> value`

Answer (score 0):

in your datapoints table you may need 4 columns. the ID will be a foreignKey, linked to you instances table.

Therefore you need to add a datapointID to have a unique identifier for the datapoint

Rgds